# Understanding My AlarmManager Logic

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, alarmmanager

I need help in understanding the logic that I have implemented in my app using `AlarmManager`, since the logic is not working as I expected. I am new to Android development and a self-learner.

**The Logic :**

User selects a time in Main Activity using a button.

That time value is used for setting repeating alarm in Another activity.

When the alarm goes of A dialog box appears.

**Main Activity:**

```
static long ATfrom_to_millisec;

case R.id.ATfrom:

        final Calendar ATfromC = Calendar.getInstance();
        ATfromHour = ATfromC.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        ATfromMinute = ATfromC.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog ATfromtpd = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                        //Converting to milli seconds to use in AlarmManager

                        ATfrom_to_millisec = ((hourOfDay * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (minute * 60 * 1000));

                        String AM_PM;
                        if (hourOfDay < 12) {
                            AM_PM = "AM";
                        } else {
                            AM_PM = "PM";
                            if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                                hourOfDay = hourOfDay - 12;
                            }
                        }

                        if (minute < 10) {
                            ATfrom.setText(hourOfDay + ":0" + minute + " " + AM_PM);
                        } else {
                            ATfrom.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute + " " + AM_PM);
                        }
```

In the above logic the time selected by the user is converted to milliseconds and stored in a public static variable so that it can be used by other activities.

**Alarm Activity :**

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (arg0.getId()){

    case R.id.bReminder:
         try {
          //Receiving the static variable's value from MainActivity
             long AT_from = MainActivity.ATfrom_to_millisec;
             float cov = (float)(AT_from/1000/60/60);
          //Toast to check if the time value is passed correctly 
             toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(cov), toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notifier.class);
             PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(),
                 12345, intent, 0);
    //Logic for Repeating Alarm that uses the time value from MainActivty as starting time and repeating it every 10 seconds.
    // i.e. the alarm should go off after 10 seconds from the use selected time and repeat after 10 seconds.
             AlarmManager am =
                 (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
             am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AT_from + (10*1000), 10*1000, pendingIntent);


           } catch (Exception e) {}

         break; 

    case R.id.bReminderStop:
        AlarmManager am =
        (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(pendingIntent);

        break;

    }
}
```

When alarm is set with the above implemented logic , The alarm goes of immediately once it is set and repeats with an interval of 1 minute.
But I implemented my logic expecting the alarm to go of 10 seconds from the time set by user and repeat after every 10 seconds
I am not able to understand the mistake implemented in my logic.
Also in the toast I am not getting the decimal value of float cov 
(eg : 11:30 PM must be displayed as 23.5 .But it is displayed as 23.0)

**Dialog Activity when Alarm goes off :**

```
public class Notifier extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("HydrateTime");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter the amount of water");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Update", null);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

I want the above Activity to be invoked when the Alarm goes off. Is the above implemented logic enough to make a Dialog window appear when an activity goes of?

**Note :** I am using a general activity definition in the Android Manifest.

**like  :**

```
<activity 
        android:name=".Notifier" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity
```

**Kindly request answers for the below questions :**

1. Am I passing the time value set in the MainActivity to the AlarmManager in another activity correctly?
2. What is the mistake in my Alarm logic and how to rectify it such that the alarm goes of as per my requirement?
3. Is the definition for the dialog box correct? should there any more definitions in Manifest? should I create any layout file for the dialog activity? Should I extend my Notifier class with Dialog class instead of Activity class?

Comment: Note: Alarm manager may not execute on time if the phone has `DOZE` function enabled. https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: Alarm is executing but not in the expected time and interval

Comment: Doze feature is not available in my device

Answer (score 0):

The logic has a minor flaw. You see, with alarms if the time to fire has already passed, then the alarm will fire immediately. For eg: if I set an alarm with milli seconds for 2 Jan 1983, it would fire immediately. If you notice, you are doing something similar.

To fix it, simply add this in your `Alarm Activity`:

```
// Will trigger after 10 secs from set time
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + AT_from + (10*1000), 10*1000, pendingIntent);
```

I am not sure what is causing the interval problem though. It seems fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. can you please verify the logic I use for dialog box?

Comment: @AkashDev you don't need any extra declaration for dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your time and advise :)